# Big-Oh Notation problem

Tags: big-o

I think the Big-O notation is n^2, but im not too sure.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n -1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n – 1; j++)
        if (x[j] > x[j+1]) {
            temp = x[j];
            x[j] = x[j+1];
            x[j+1] = temp;
        }
}
```

Comment: Im just practicing for the exam

Comment: In the future, please format your code by indenting it by four spaces or selecting it and using the 1010 button at the top of the question editor.

Comment: Yes, it is O(n^2). And don't add unnecessary (and wrong) tags such as PHP.

Comment: that was a typo . im sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing N * (N * (4)) operations = O(N^2)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's n^2.  Ignore the constants, outer loops run n times, and inner loop runs n times for each n.